# Python run 2 async infinite loops after the first one already started

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-asyncio

I want to run 2 infinite async loops that should run simultanoesly.

However though, they are not called together.

The first loop starts running immediately and when it detects something it calls the second loop and they should run independently.

Something like this:

```
async def test():
    while True:
        print("test")
        time.sleep(7)


async def call_test():
    loopd = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task = loopd.create_task(test())
    await task


async def print_main():
    while True:
        print("main")
        await call_test()
        time.sleep(5)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(print_main())
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PS:
There are a lot of similar questions, but they all run 2 independent loops from the start.

Comment: use multiple tasks instead of "nested" event loops

Comment: can u explain ?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is replace all the time.sleep calls with await asyncio.sleep.  Then you need to add logic so that you create exactly one additional infinite loop after the first one starts; in other words, you create the task `test()` only once.  Then you must not await this task, since `await`ing an infinite loop doesn't make much sense (you will wait forever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use `time.sleep` with `asyncio` loop in the same thread, otherwise `time.sleep` will block all other tasks of the `asyncio` loop.
2. You need only one `asyncio` loop in one thread, because only one loop can do work simultaneously in the same thread.

Your code will work with the following changes:

```py
import asyncio


async def test():
    while True:
        print("test")
        await asyncio.sleep(7)


async def print_main():
    another_task = None
    while True:
        print("main")
        if another_task is None:
            another_task = asyncio.create_task(test())
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(print_main())
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```